# Structure of p2p network in Ethereum

Tags: network, p2p

We now know that the blockchain runs on a p2p network and that the information is driven by gossip algorithms. Is the structure on p2p used in ethereum a simple structure like you can find on simple explanatory websites?
(A simple structure is one in which each node is connected to multiple nodes that are connected by a certain algorithm.)
Or is the structure devised in some way to improve the efficiency of data transmission?
I would also appreciate it if you could provide me with any references that would answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum's p2p network indeed follows a structure where each node connects to multiple others, but it's more sophisticated than the simple diagrams often found on introductory websites.

It utilizes the Kademlia algorithm for efficient routing and node discovery.

This algorithm organizes nodes into "buckets" based on a distance metric, facilitating quick data lookup and transmission.

For a deeper dive into Ethereum's network protocol, the Ethereum Yellow Paper provides a comprehensive technical overview (see section 4.3, "The Network").